# Is there a way to answer this 'I can't find a job!' question?

Tags: discussion

[Guidance for entry level job seeker](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/24413/entry-level-unemployed)

This question is clearly not very good quality. It comes from place of frustration from the user.

However, it *is* a common problem that this person is facing, and point of this stack exchange is *to be useful*.

So how can we, perhaps edit and answer, this question such that is useful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a question like this, the best thing to do is to close it as too broad as quickly as possible. The sooner the better. Most importantly, it's critical that someone leave a nice, friendly comment explaining that the goal is simply to give the asker more time to answer some of the clarifying questions from the comments.

The comment should essentially emphasize that we really want to provide the best value we can, and to reduce clutter in the answers, we've put the post temporarily on hold just to give the asker a breather -- a chance to add more helpful details.

Aside from that, we can't really help with initial editing because we simply don't know what the full scope of the problem is, but what you *can* do is add more clarifying questions in the comments. The nice thing about these questions is that, with an asker who understands we're here to help, there's a very strong chance we can turn the post into something not just useful for the asker but also to future readers with the same problem.

For really broad questions, think of clarifying comments as a way to draw out information that you would personally edit into the question, if you knew that information existed.

Hope this helps, and thanks for bringing attention to this post. I've put it on hold temporarily, so please vote to reopen once there are more details.

Comment: How do I find a job is off topic though...